# Response code 400 for get https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full

Tags: ruby, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I use https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby library for fetch and save data to google spreadsheet

i have run code:

```
session = GoogleDrive.login(login, password)
file = session.spreadsheet_by_title(title)

file.human_url
```

And have such error:

```
GoogleDrive::Error: Response code 400 for get https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/spreadsheet%3AtwgjwnVyrjJFjTh0U9UZRlA: Invalid document id: spreadsheet:twgjwnVyrjJFjTh0U9UZRlA
```

from /google_drive/lib/google_drive/session.rb:411:in `request'

If i use

```
file = session.spreadsheet_by_key(key)
```

the code "file.human_url" works fine

How i can resolve such error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, after using the gem successfully months prior. This can be fixed in the Gem by both appending GData-Version & updating the document_feed_url in spreadsheet.rb

You can use my pull request as a reference: https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/pull/78